# jquery datatables obtain id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, initialization

I'm initializing the `.dataTable()` the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var articles_table = $("table#datatable-articles").dataTable({
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'rowHeight': 'auto',
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        'sAjaxSource': '/admin/articles/data',
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    });
```

Then, I'm trying to get the `id` value that is in the `tbody > tr > td:first` and save it in a variable, and then hide the field. No luck, everything that I tried, didn't work.

```
    var ex = $('table#datatable-articles');
    if ( $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( ex ) ) {
        console.log(ex.find('tbody tr td:first'));
        ex.find('tbody tr td:first').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    }
```

/

```
    articles_table.$('tbody tr:odd').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    console.log(articles_table.find('tbody tr td:first').val());
    articles_table.find('tbody tr td:first').html('1');
```

All the above executes on dom ready, but then the `dataTable` is initialized and replaces everything with its data

The basic question is: How to obtain the id value from the table data and then hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, and it works...

inside `dataTable()` have added the following

```
        'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            $(nRow).attr("data-id",aData[0]);
            return nRow;
        }
```